# Is there a name / set for characters that can be typed using a standard english keyboard?

Tags: character

Is there a name / set for characters that can be typed using a standard english keyboard?

Comment: My last option is saying 'typeable characters'.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a "standard english keyboard" - for example different keyboards are used in the US and Britain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase I think you are looking for is the Latin alphabet, or the ASCII character set.

Comment: I think ASCII should settle it.

Comment: My english keyboard has lots of characters that are not ASCII  ¬ ` ¦ 
And - being a proper english keyboard - it also has £ which is not ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [ASCII printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)

(you can also use the term [Graphic character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_character))